# Adding some lines to my Block diagram in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

The objective is to draw feedback lines from the output to both the MPC and PID, as illustrated in the accompanying images.

```
\documentclass[border=3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth, auto, node distance=2cm, thick]
% Create nodes
\node[draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm] (MPC) at (0,0) {MPC};
\node[draw, circle, minimum size=0.6cm, right=of MPC] (sum){};
\node[draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, below=of MPC] (PID) {PID};
\node[draw, rectangle, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, right=of sum] (MPD) {MPD System};

% Connect nodes
\draw[-] (sum.north east) -- (sum.south west);
\draw[-] (sum.south east) -- (sum.north west);
\draw[->] (MPC) -- node[pos=0.5] {$u_{\text{MPC}}(t)$} (sum.west);
\draw[->] (PID.east) -| node[pos=0.25, above] {$u_{\text{PID}}(t)$} (sum.south);
\draw[->] (sum.east) -- node {$u(t)$} (MPD.west);
\draw[->] (MPD.east) -- node[pos=0.8] {} ++(1,0);
\draw[<-] ([yshift=+0.2cm]MPC.west) -- node[pos=0.8] {} ++(-1.5,0);
\draw[->] ([xshift=-0.8cm,yshift=+0.2cm]MPC.west) |-  ([yshift=+0.2cm]PID.west);

% Add labels
\node[above left=-.3 and 0.9cm of MPC] {Ref.};
\node[right=1cm of MPD] {$P_{\text{bit}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would greatly appreciate your guidance on integrating the feedback lines seamlessly into the existing code. Additionally, if you have any suggestions to enhance the professionalism of the block diagram or any alternative approaches, I am open to considering them.

For a clearer understanding, I have attached relevant images depicting the current state and the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most systematic way may be using [package blox](https://ctan.org/pkg/blox) or similar.

However, if you want to do it manually, here's one way to do it:

- being lazy, I just dropped the math-modes (almost) // it's easy to add and obscures the code a bit more
- by its very nature this drawing is a bit intermingled
- put the blocks + the cross for the sum
- draw the various connections
- put extra nodes for rectangular lines where needed, using polar coordinate notation e.g. at the input side
- put most nodes for labels within these paths (which makes it a bit harder to read)
- intentionally put the polarities extra at the end, though they could have been in said paths as well (making code even less legible) (I used math-mode here as the minus sign is a bit longer, then)
- I put some empty nodes and a coordinate where you want the dots

I think you don't need the dots and humps for the connections here.

It's tempting to use `{Circle}` here, like so

```
 \draw[{Circle}-{Circle}] (A) -- (B);
```

to mimick the dots, but then you have to pronlong the arrow a bit or shift its tip.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}% just my preference
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,
    > = {Stealth},
    blks/.style={draw, minimum width=20mm,inner sep=4mm},
    sum/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=6mm},
 ]
    % ~~~ blocks ~~~~~~~~~
    \node[blks]             (M) at (0,0) {MPC};     
    \node[blks,below=of M]  (P)          {PID};     
    \node[sum,right=of M]   (S)          {};            % sum
    \node[blks,right=of S]  (Y)          {MPD system};
    %     cross
    \draw[-] (S.north east) -- (S.south west);
    \draw[-] (S.south east) -- (S.north west);

    
    % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~
    % --- output
    \draw[->] (Y.east) -- node[pos=0.5](O){} +(1.3,0)node[anchor=west]{Pbit};   
    
    %--- inside, mixed with labels
    \draw[->] (M.east) -- node{uMPC(t)}                         (S.west);
    \draw[->] (P.east) -| node[anchor=south,pos=.25]{uPID(t)}   (S.south);
    \draw[->] (S.east) -- node{u(t)}                            (Y.west);
    
    %--- feedbacks
    \draw[<->]  (P.190) -- +(-1.3,0) coordinate (D) |- (M.190);
    \draw       (D)     -- +(0,-1.5)                -| (O);
    
    %--- input
    \draw[<-] (M.170) --  +(-2,0) 
                            node[pos=.35,anchor=center,inner sep=0pt] (I) {}
                            node[anchor=south]{Ref.};
    \draw[->] (I) |- (P.170);
    
    % ~~~ polarities ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[red,xshift=3mm] at (P.170) {$+$};
    \node[red,xshift=3mm] at (P.190) {$-$};
    
    \node[red,xshift=-4mm,yshift=-3mm] at (S.west)  {$+$};
    \node[red,xshift=+4mm,yshift=-3mm] at (S.south) {$+$};
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```